# Triggering element style changes/transforms from within react

Tags: css, reactjs

I have a range-slider component and have it console.logging output whenever the slider is changed/moved/incremented. I want this to trigger a change in the scale of a css shape on my page so the css shape grows in size as you increment the volume slider from 1 to 10. I currently have my css styling sitting in separate .scss files. What is the correct way to scale it?

Answer (score 0):

How about declaring the scale inline (I haven't tested this)?:

```
const styles = { 
    transform: `scale(${x}%` 
};

return (
    <element style={styles}></element>
);
```

Where x is your variable being modified by the slider